# Packaging a native library into an APK

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, eclipse-3.6, android-3.1-honeycomb

How do I do this from Eclipse? I can't find any way. I tried creating a `build.xml` with the following and adding it as the final builder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MobileRecovery" default="mergelibs">
<loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" />
<property file="ant.properties" />
<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
<fail unless="sdk.dir" message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project'" />
<!-- version-tag: custom -->
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
<target name="mergelibs">
    <apkbuilder outfolder="bin" verbose="true" apkfilepath="bin/MobileRecovery.apk">
        <file path="bin/classes.dex" />
        <nativefolder path="libs" />
    </apkbuilder>
</target>
</project>
```

but all that achieves is the output `apkbuilder doesn't support the nested "file" element`.

At this point I'm not interested in the whys and hows of what I'm doing wrong, if someone can just give me a solution that WORKS I'll figure out the theory behind it.

Comment: I have native lib in \libs\armeabi dir on my project and Eclipse places it into APK without efforts from my side. Try to just place your library in such directory.

Comment: @ggurov That worked, THANKS! Please answer the question so I can give you some points!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your native library in \libs\armeabi directory of your project folder and Eclipse will put it in the package.