# creating, installing and running a NATIVE android application/service

Tags: android, service, native

My company has 2 native applications that run on Windows/Mac/Linux as services or daemons.  I have taken this code and compiled it with the Android toolchain.  I have a rooted android device to which I can push this application, run as as process and it works great.  However, I'd like to build some sort of installer (probably an .apk) to which I could add this native application and run on ANY android device (e.g. without being rooted).
So does anybody know of a link, example or even just how to "install" a native application and run?
Thanks
/Loren

Comment: [Here][1] is the similar question. And answer is available. Please check.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853732/packaging-a-native-library-into-an-apk

Comment: Thanks.  But I do put my application in the proj_dir/libs/armeabi-v7a directory and I don't see it in the data/data/com.blah.blah/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly, you need to rework your native service to be a library utilized by an android Service, and operate in keeping with android's conception of services (lifecycle, status bar notification, etc).

Trying to run your own executable (vs library to an android-provided executable) is not something android makes easy and not something you are encouraged to do.